# I need the texts to show at the bottom inside buttons In Android. used android:paddingBottom, but not working

Tags: android, android-button

I need the texts to show at the bottom inside buttons, but its not working after using `paddingBottom`. they keep showing at the center, not moving at all. Any help would be really appreciable. Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bakgrunn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bakgrunnsbilde" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Add a drink" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Edit/delete drink" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Graph" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Profile" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gravity for your Buttons

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

PaddingBottom will make text Farther from bottom edges

Comment: heyy, Thank you so much, I really forgot that before we adjust the text using padding in Button, we need to add gravity. Thanks :)

Comment: yw ,accpeting the answer would be nice as well.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Add a drink"
        android:gravity="bottom"
     />
```